# Neo4j Bloom is missing nodes for apoc.path.subgraphAll while Neo4j Desktop Browser works as expected

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, neo4j-apoc, bloom

So when I run the following query against my DB I get 168 nodes returned.

```
MATCH (u:Undefined)
CALL apoc.path.subgraphNodes(u, {}) YIELD node
RETURN node
```

This works as expected in both Neo4j Bloom (1.3.2) and Desktop Browser (1.2.8)

If I run this query, so I can get the relationships as well, then I get 154 nodes returned in Bloom, while Desktop Browser still correctly returns 168 nodes as expected.

```
MATCH (u:Undefined)
CALL apoc.path.subgraphAll(u, {}) YIELD nodes, relationships
RETURN nodes, relationships
```

In my graph 154 of the nodes are tied together in this query, in one big inter-connected clump. There are 3 other small clumps of 3, 3 and 8 nodes, that make up the missing 14 nodes. These are what is being missed in Bloom.

Am I missing something? Is there an issue in Bloom?

Anyone have a better idea on how I can return all nodes and relationships, that start at a given node type/label, in Bloom, if this doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Neo4j Bloom doesn't handle an array of nodes and an array of relationships as an input. Try the following query:

```
MATCH (u:Undefined)
CALL apoc.path.subgraphAll(u, {}) YIELD nodes, relationships
UNWIND relationships as rel
RETURN startNode(rel),rel,endNode(rel)
```

Not sure if it will work. You could also try and use an APOC procedure that returns paths like for example `apoc.path.expand`.